# Dropdown menu over a background image cause overflow issues

Tags: html, css

In theory when I step over the dropdown menu it should open normally and allow me to click until I exit the menu area, instead when I step over it and try to go down to select the menu disappears, I know it's an overflow problem but I can't seem to out of it I have already tried with the z-index

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Serif:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap");
body {
    margin: 0;
}
/*
#topcontainer{
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
} Vedere zia*/
#subcontainer {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}
ul#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 9;
    flex-direction: row;
}
ul#nav li {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
}
ul#nav li a {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ebebeb;
}
.Ilink {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
.Ilink:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
#logol {
    margin: 0 0 0 20;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: center;
    flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
#textr {
    margin: 0 20 0 0;
    line-height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: center;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    font-size: 20;
    color: white;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cont {
    margin: 11 0 0 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    min-width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.cont a {
    color: white;
    padding: 0 16 0 16;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    float: none;
    font-size: 25;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cont a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .cont {
    display: block;
}
#princ {
    background-image: url(./Immagini/princ.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000;
    z-index: 0;
}
#ptcont {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 68%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 0;
}
#princt {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}
#subt {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}
#textc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 3;
}
#textcs {
    height: 70%;
    padding: 0 10 0 40;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Roboto Serif", serif;
    color: white;
}
#topbanner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(./Immagini/header-menu1.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#bgcont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(./Immagini/sfondo-menup.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
}
#contcont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#footcontainer {
    background-color: #363636;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Trattoria - HOME</title>
        <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="subcontainer">
                <img id="logol" src="./Immagini/logo.png" width="100px" height="50px" />
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="./index.html" class="Ilink">Home</a></li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <li id="drop">
                            <a href="./Pagine/#" class="Ilink">
                                Menù
                                <svg width="20" height="15" viewBox="-2.5 -5 75 60" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                                    <path d="M0,0 l35,50 l35,-50" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="5" />
                                </svg>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <div class="cont">
                            <a href="#" class="Ilink">Antipasti</a><br />
                            <a href="#" class="Ilink">Primi</a><br />
                            <a href="#" class="Ilink">Secondi</a><br />
                            <a href="#" class="Ilink">Dolci</a><br />
                            <a href="#" class="Ilink">Piatti del giorno</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <li><a href="#Chisiamo" class="Ilink">Chi Siamo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./Pagine/#" class="Ilink">Aiuto</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="Ilink"><p id="textr">Accedi/Registrati</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You added hover to `.dropdown` so it affects both `.dropdown` and all of his children. This part is ok.

The issue is that you have a gap between the menu item `#drop` and the dropdown `.cont`. When you move the cursor down, at some point you come across this gap. That is when you are longer pointing to `.dropdown` or to any of the children so the `.dropdown` loses his hover state. To fix this, you need to eliminate this gap either by changing the size of the elements or by moving them closer together.

My original answer was to replace the margin with the padding in `.cont`, so the `.cont` is tall enough to eliminate this gap, but now i think a better solution would be to change the padding inside `ul#nav li a` element. If you change:

```
ul#nav li a {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ebebeb;
}
```

to:

```
ul#nav li a {
    padding: 25px 20px;
    color: #ebebeb;
}
```

the appearance will not change but the link will cover the entire height of the header and the gap will disappear completely - the hover will be kept.

Comment: It works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change margin to padding in `.cont` class

```
.cont{  
        padding: 11 0 0 0;
        opacity: 0.9;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #1f1f1f;
        min-width: 400px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
```